# Xamarin Forms Could Not Find DataContext

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, mvvm, binding

I am trying to bind properties of views in the view page to a class that I have in a carpet called ViewModel, and then from an instance of another class called Category (a model) in a carpet called Model I am trying to access to properties contained there, the problem is that it does not seem to work .Although there are no error codes in the codes, I cannot access the bindings when I run the application. The warning I get is:
Datacontext not found for binding SelectedCategory .CategoryName(I get the same warning in ProductItemByCategory binding)
Do you have any solution suggestions?
Thank You!!

I will explain it with more details in the code:

**1.CategoryView.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:pancake="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView" 

        
         x:Class="DirencNetClone.Views.CategoryView">
 <ContentPage.Content>
    
    <ScrollView>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>


            <Label Grid.Row="1"  Text="{Binding SelectedCategory.CategoryName}" FontSize="Body" Margin="25,-85,0,0" TextColor="Black" />

            <ImageButton Source="logo.png" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Aspect="AspectFill" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="10,30" Clicked="ImageButton_Clicked"/>
            <pancake:PancakeView Grid.Row="2" BackgroundColor="Wheat" Margin="0,40">
                <Grid Padding="25,30" >
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TotalProductItems,StringFormat= '{0} Total Items'}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black"/>
                    <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Source="info.png"/>
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ProductItemsByCategory}"
                                        VerticalOptions="Start" 
                                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                        SelectionMode="Single"
                                        SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout>
                                    <Frame HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White" HeightRequest="90" Margin="0,10">
                                        <Grid >
                                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

                                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                            <pancake:PancakeView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="3" Margin="0,0,10,0 "  >
                                                <Image  Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HeightRequest="100" WidthRequest="95" Aspect="AspectFill"/>

                                            </pancake:PancakeView>
                                            <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="15"  TextColor="Black"/>
                                            <Label  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Description}" FontSize="15"  TextColor="Black"/>
                                            <Label Grid.Row="2 " Grid.Column="1" Margin="30,0,0,0" VerticalOptions="Center" FontSize="15" >
                                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                                    <FormattedString>
                                                        <Span Text="{Binding Rating}" FontAttributes="Bold" />
                                                        <Span Text="{Binding RatingDetail} " TextColor="Yellow"/>
                                                    </FormattedString>
                                                </Label.FormattedText>
                                            </Label>
                                            <Image Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Source="{Binding HomeSelected}" HeightRequest="15"/>
                                            <Label  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Price}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black"/>

                                        </Grid>

                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>

                    </CollectionView>
                </Grid>
            </pancake:PancakeView>

        </Grid>
    </ScrollView>

</ContentPage.Content>
```

**2.CategoryViewModel.cs**

```
public class CategoryViewModel:BaseViewModel
{

    private   Category _SelectedCategory;
    public Category SelectedCategory
    {
        set
        {
            _SelectedCategory = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return _SelectedCategory;
        }
    }




    public ObservableCollection<ProductItem> ProductItemsByCategory { get; set; }

   private  int _TotalProductItems;
    public int TotalProductItems
    {
        set
        {
            this._TotalProductItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return this._TotalProductItems;
        }
    }

    public CategoryViewModel( Category category)
    {
        SelectedCategory = category;
  

        ProductItemsByCategory = new ObservableCollection<ProductItem>();
     

        GetProductItems(category.CategoryID);

    }

     async void GetProductItems(int categoryID)
    {
        var data = await new ProductItemService().GetProductItemsByCategoryAsync(categoryID);

        ProductItemsByCategory.Clear();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            ProductItemsByCategory.Add(item);
        }
        TotalProductItems = ProductItemsByCategory.Count;
    }
    
}
```

**3.Category.cs(Model)**

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    
}
```

**4.CategoryView.cs**

```
public partial class CategoryView : ContentPage
{
    CategoryViewModel cvm;

    public CategoryView(Category category )
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cvm = new CategoryViewModel(category);
        this.BindingContext=cvm
       
        

           ;
    }

    async void ImageButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();

    }

    async void CollectionView_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var selectedProduct = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as ProductItem;
        if (selectedProduct == null)
            return;
        await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new ProductsDetailsView(selectedProduct));
        ((CollectionView)sender).SelectedItem = null;

    }
}
```

**5.BaseViewModel**

```
public  class BaseViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string name = null) =>
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));

  
}
```

**6.ProductItem(Model)**

```
 public class ProductItem
{
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
    public  string Rating { get; set;
            }
    public string Description { get; set;
    }
    public string RatingDetail { get; set; }
    public string HomeSelected { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

**7.ProductView.xaml**

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="DirencNetClone.Views.ProductsView"
         
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:DirencNetClone.ViewModels"
         xmlns:pancake ="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
         >
<ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <vm:ProductsViewModel/>
</ContentPage.BindingContext>

<ContentPage.Content>

    <Grid Margin="20,0,0,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>


            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="logo.png " Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding UserEmail} " Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" FontSize="Body"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="ic_menu_categories.png"  Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="End"/>
            <Label Text="{Binding UserCartItemsCount}" FontSize="Subtitle" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Start"/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="ic_menu_basket.png" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                         Command="{Binding ViewCartCommand } "/>
            <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="ic_menu_profile.png" Margin="0,0,10,0" HorizontalOptions="End" Command="{Binding LogoutCommand}"/>
        </Grid>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <SearchBar Grid.Column="0" Placeholder="Ürün Ara" BackgroundColor="Transparent" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
        </Grid>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories} " 
                        Margin="0,20"
                        HeightRequest="125"
                        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                        ItemsLayout="HorizontalList"
                        SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged"
                        SelectionMode="Single"
                        Grid.Row="2">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Frame HeightRequest="50" HasShadow="False" BackgroundColor="White" CornerRadius="10">
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}"/>
                        </Frame>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CategoryName}  " HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>


        </CollectionView>
        <Label Grid.Row="3" Text="Latest Items" FontSize="25" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding  LatestItems}" Margin="0,20,10,0" VerticalOptions="Start" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Never" Grid.Row="4">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackLayout>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto "/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <pancake:PancakeView Grid.Row="0" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageUrl}" HeightRequest="220" Aspect="Fill"/>
                            </pancake:PancakeView>
                            <Frame Grid.Row="1" Margin="20,-80,20,70" BackgroundColor="Wheat" HorizontalOptions="End">
                                <Label Text="{Binding Price,StringFormat='{0:c}'}" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" TextColor="Black" HeightRequest="10"/>

                            </Frame>
                            <Label Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize=" 22" FontAttributes="Bold" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                            <Label Grid.Row="2" Margin="30,0,0,0" FontSize="15" VerticalOptions="Center" >
                                <Label.FormattedText>
                                    <FormattedString>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding Rating}" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                                        <Span Text="{Binding Description}" TextColor="White"/>
                                    </FormattedString>
                                </Label.FormattedText>
                            </Label>
                                   
                        </Grid>
                    </StackLayout>
                  
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>

    </Grid>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

**8.ProductViewModel**

```
public   class ProductsViewModel :BaseViewModel
{
    private string _UserEMail;
    public string UserEmail
    {
        set
        {
            this._UserEMail = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return this._UserEMail;
        }

    }

    public ObservableCollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ProductItem> LatestItems { get; set; }

    private int _UserCartItemsCount;
    public int UserCartItemsCount
    {
        set
        {
            this._UserCartItemsCount = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
        get
        {
            return this._UserCartItemsCount;
        }
    }


    public Command ViewCartCommand { get; set; }
    public Command LogoutCommand
    {
        get; set;
    }

    public ProductsViewModel()
    {
        var uemail = Preferences.Get("UserEmail", String.Empty);
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(uemail))
            UserEmail = "Guest";
        else
            UserEmail = uemail;
        UserCartItemsCount = new CartItemService().GetUserCartCount();
        Categories = new ObservableCollection<Category>();
        LatestItems = new ObservableCollection<ProductItem>();
        GetCategories();
        GetLatestItems();
        ViewCartCommand = new Command(async () => ViewCartAsync());
        LogoutCommand = new Command(async () => await LogoutAsync());


    }

   async void GetLatestItems()
    {
        var data = await new ProductItemService().GetLatestProductItemsAsync();
        LatestItems.Clear();
        foreach(var item in data)
        {
            LatestItems.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private async Task LogoutAsync()
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new LogoutVew());
    }

    private async void GetCategories()
    {
        var data = await new CategoryDataService().GetCategoriesAsync();
        Categories.Clear();
        foreach (var item in data)
        {
            Categories.Add(item);
        }
    }

    private async Task ViewCartAsync()
    {
        await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new CartView());
    }
```

Comment: this appears correct at first glance to me.  Are you maybe assigning a BindingContext in your XAML also?

Comment: 1) Show the lines of CategoryView.xaml, that are before `<ContentPage.Content>`. 2)  are you testing on ios, android, or uwp?

Comment: 3) `BaseViewModel` - are you using an MVVM library? If so, which one. If not, please show the declaration line(s) from the source for that class, something like `public class BaseViewModel : ... {`  I want to see what interfaces are implemented. Might somehow be related to "Datacontext not found".

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve  2)I am testin on Android . 3) I am using MVVM library . Additionally I added productView.xaml and ProductViewModel classes. I didn't have any binding problem in ProductView.xaml

Comment: @Jason I set the bindingDataContext as CategoryViewmodel, but this time I get the same error in bindings (Binding ImageUrl), (Binding Name ) etc.

Comment: if you post your solution somewhere I can download it I'll take a quick look

Comment: please learn to use gitignore, your repo is filled with stuff that doesn't need to be there.  https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: get rid of `x:DataType="viewmodels:CartViewModel"`

Comment: I don't see what would cause this. Lets make sure the project is in a clean state:  Delete your project's `bin` and `obj` folders. Build/run again.

Comment: @Jason https://github.com/omermaestro10/DirencNetClone.git

Comment: Did you try to ignore this warning and compile the project ？

Comment: Yes I did  but A blank page appears when I should be viewing products

Comment: Did you try to move      `cvm = new CategoryViewModel(category);`
        `this.BindingContext=cvm` to OnAppearing method ?